# Copy cells with styles with PHPExcel

Tags: php, styles, phpexcel

I am a beginner in PHP trying to display a .xls sheet in a div with PHPExcel.
So far, i've come up with :

```
require_once './PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("telephone.xls");


$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);

echo '<table border="0">';


foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
  echo '<tr>';


  foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
    echo '<td>';
    print_r($cell->getValue());
    echo '</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

But of course it displays a simple table with no formatting and i can't figure out how to import the styles. (For example, title backgound is purple, footer is purple, etc...)

Any idea on how to do that ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Joris

Comment: Why don't you use PHPExcel's HTML Writer to do it for you? That's exactly what the HTML Writer is for!

Comment: you can add inline css when you are echoing the table rows and columns

Comment: @MarkBaker Indeed it works fine with the style, i didn't see this function. Just one problem, it prints 255 columns. How can i select the 3 i need ?

Comment: It prints as many columns as required.... if your sheet prints 255, then that's because there is something in the 255th column, even if that something is a cell containing a space or null, or a style definition.... you can always try just reading 3 columns using a read filter

Comment: @MarkBaker I used the method on the documentation, but there still are ghosts cells : [picture](https://puu.sh/tpiug/984679a0ab.png)

Comment: Does anybody have an idea ?